# readxl having problems with detecting and converting dates

Tags: r, excel, date

I´m new to R ... maybe you can help me with this.
When I import my dataset ba_data from Excel into R, the columns STARTED and LASTDATA show values that don´t exist in my excel sheet. R reads those columns as characters, but what is shown in the table in R doesn´t even make sense and doesn´t look like the numbers from excel.
In excel they are shown as dates: y/m/d /h/min/sec.
I tried to convert them into dates with the following code. If I run the code, everything turns into NA.

```
#I used this to import my datafile               
ba_data <- read_excel(choose.files(), na = "-9")

#tried to convert STARTED and LASTDATA to date
ba_data$STARTED <- anytime::anydate(ba_data$STARTED)
ba_data$LASTDATA <- anytime::anydate(ba_data$LASTDATA)
```

Comment: `y/m/d /h/min/sec` isn't a date.  It's a datetime.  You say you get data in R that wasn't in yourExcel file.  But you don't show us either.  It's going to be hard to help you without that sort of information.  But welcome to SO all the same.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

```r
ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")] <- 
  lapply(ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")], as.POSIXct,
         format = "%Y/%m/%d /%H/%M/%S")
```

will convert both columns to `POSIXct` (timestamp).

If you need them to be `Date`s (losing the time information), then

1. *follow* the above with

   ```r
   ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")] <- lapply(ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")], as.Date)
   ```
2. *replace* the above with

   ```r
   ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")] <-
     lapply(ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")],
            function(z) as.Date(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y/%m/%d /%H/%M/%S")))
   ```
3. truncate the string before convertion, *replacing* the above with

   ```r
   ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")] <-
     lapply(ba_data[c("STARTED","LASTDATA")],
            function(z) as.Date(sub(" .*", "", z)))
   ```

I'm inferring by `y/m/d` you mean 4-digit years. If it's 2-digit years, change all `%Y` above to lower-case `%y`.

Untested.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Yes, by y/m/d I mean 4-digit years. However, both ways didn´t work. Maybe something went wrong when importing the data?

Comment: By the way, welcome to SO! If you have not already, please take the [tour] (suggested by a non-reproducible question, though this is an above-average first-question :-). To get more-targeted help, as suggested in the tour and in https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info, sample data is really really helpful; please read about using `dput` or similar for sharing sample data. Thanks!